# $f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$ iff $f|_A (x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

[image]

From below, it is the proof of the second proposition.

[image]

For the first part of the proof, I don't understand the statement 'if $x$ is in $A \setminus\{c\}$, then $x$ is in $S \setminus \{c\}$, and hence $f|_A(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$.'.

Of course, "if $x$ is in $A \setminus\{c\}$, then $x$ is in $S \setminus \{c\}$" is true, but we only know $x\in S \setminus \{c\}$, but do not know "$x \in A \setminus \{c\}$", then how does it help prove "$f|_A(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course if $A\subseteq S$, anything in $A$ must be contained in $S$, so $x\in A-\{c\}$ implies that $x\in S-\{c\}$. And out goal is to prove that, whether or not, we have something like $\big|f|_{A}(x)-L\big|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in A-\{c\}$.

So we must first assume that $x\in A-\{c\}$, and then we judge whether or not we have the conclusion that $\big|f|_{A}(x)-L\big|<\epsilon$. And this is successfully done because we have the premise that if $x\in S-\{c\}$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: The first part of the proof is "$f(x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$ $\longrightarrow$ $f|_A (x) \rightarrow L$ as $x \rightarrow c$". But, can we assume $x \in A \setminus \{c\}$, which is the part of what we want to prove?

Comment: You just assume the first part of the conditional statement: $x\in A-\{c\}$, you are not assuming that you have had the conclusion. And you must assume the first part of the conditional statement, if not, you can't even proceed the proof. To prove that $p\rightarrow q$, we assume $p$ first, and then try to find some means to prove we have the $q$. This is different than assuming both $p$ and $q$, which makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. I agree  that we can assume that $x \in S \setminus \{c\}$, and this does not imply $x \in A \setminus \{c\}$ since $A \subset S$. Do you mean we can assume  $x \in A \setminus \{c\}$  again?

Comment: Yes, and we are forced to assume that $x\in A-\{c\}$, this is the very first step to start to prove whether $p\rightarrow q$, $p=A-\{c\}$, $q=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I think I get it . Thanks!!